# Convert For-Each into a LINQ query for adding items in list and check wehter list contains the item already

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq

I would like to convert ForEach to LINQ. Currently I'm using these two parts

```
If TypeOf e.FilterPopup Is RadListFilterPopup Then
    Dim ePopup As RadListFilterPopup = DirectCast(e.FilterPopup, RadListFilterPopup)

    Dim childList As New List(Of Object)()
    For Each row As GridViewRowInfo In Me.grdCNCFilesRad.ChildRows

        Dim value = row.Cells(e.Column.Index).Value
        If Not childList.Contains(value) Then
            childList.Add(value)
        End If
    Next


    Dim newPopup As New RadListFilterPopup(e.Column)

    For Each item As System.Collections.ArrayList In ePopup.MenuTreeElement.DistinctListValues.Values
        If Not childList.Contains(item(0)) Then
            newPopup.MenuTreeElement.DistinctListValues.Remove(item(0).ToString())
        End If
    Next

    e.FilterPopup = newPopup
End If
```

How can I do the same with a LINQ query?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? It'd be better if you could show your work first, so that community can help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your variable `grdCNCFilesRad` is type of, but I assume it is no .NET type. But when I read `ChildRows` then I can be sure that this is some sort of enumeration (somewhere in it's inheritance tree must be the interface `IEnumerable`).

So you can include `System.Linq` and apply a `AsQueryable()` at your `ChildRows`.

The rest is just a little bit of Linq (Select, Where, ToList()). That's it!

Edit:
The first part should be solved by this:

```
Dim childList =
    Me.grdCNCFilesRad.ChildRows
        .AsQueryble()
        .Select(Function(row) row.Cells(e.Column.Index).Value)
        .Distinct()
```

Comment: Dim newPopup As New RadListFilterPopup(e.Column)

    For Each item As System.Collections.ArrayList In ePopup.MenuTreeElement.DistinctListValues.Values
        If Not childList.Contains(item(0)) Then
            newPopup.MenuTreeElement.DistinctListValues.Remove(item(0).ToString())
        End If
    Next

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of converting `ForEach` with `Linq` if you go for performance issues.

Your existing `foreach` code looks good.

Note: Don't think `Linq` is better compared to `for-each` in performance.